# How to move UITableView cells while using UITableViewDiffableDataSource?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am trying to make my `tableView cells` movable, but it needs 2 or 3 functions from `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, If I tried to implement the delegate in my `viewController` It will ask for `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` functions which are already covered by the new `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`.

How can I achieve this behavior while using the new `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`?

Comment: unfortunately moveRow and canMove are UITableViewDataSource methods... have you some news about this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To flesh out [Tung Fam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5999975/tung-fam)'s answer, here is a complete implementation:

```
class MovableTableViewDataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Int> {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        super.tableView(tableView, moveRowAt: sourceIndexPath, to: destinationIndexPath)

        var snapshot = self.snapshot()
        if let sourceId = itemIdentifier(for: sourceIndexPath) {
            if let destinationId = itemIdentifier(for: destinationIndexPath) {
                guard sourceId != destinationId else {
                    return // destination is same as source, no move.
                }
                // valid source and destination
                if sourceIndexPath.row > destinationIndexPath.row {
                    snapshot.moveItem(sourceId, beforeItem: destinationId)
                } else {
                    snapshot.moveItem(sourceId, afterItem: destinationId)
                }
            } else {
                // no valid destination, eg. moving to the last row of a section
                snapshot.deleteItems([sourceId])
                snapshot.appendItems([sourceId], toSection: snapshot.sectionIdentifiers[destinationIndexPath.section])
            }
        }

        apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

It will crash if `animatingDifferences` is set true (animating is not really desirable here anyway).

I'm not sure whether calling `super.tableView(move…)` is necessary, but it doesn't seem to do any harm.

Comment: This answer seems to have a problem: "if sourceIndexPath.row > destinationIndexPath.row" assumes both source and destination are in the same Section, which may not be true. Each section has it's own 0...n row numbering.

Comment: Note: Edited this (excellent) answer to include additional logic for paying attention to source/destination section when deciding where to snapshot.moveItem( ).

Comment: And I'll also point out in case it applies to anyone: if you keep your "source of truth" model data external to your TableView, just altering the snapshot from the table view does *not* also update your model data. That's a separate thing you have to do yourself.

Comment: Interesting, this does not work on iOS 14 (Xcode 12.2). Any other setup needed? Such as `tableView.isEditing = true`?

Comment: @WildCat, yes the UITableView needs to be in editing mode for cell reordering, `isEditing = true`. You may also need to set the cell's editing mode to `.none`, as I recall this is done in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

Comment: @alexkent Thanks for your reply but unfortunately I did this setup but it does not work for me.

Comment: I checked both `canEdit` and `canMove` but they don't work as expected. Event if I can make the reorder control visible, the leading delete button cannot be removed. Demo: https://github.com/imWildCat/DiffableDataSourceTableViewEditingDemo

Comment: @wildcat you need to implement `shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt` to return false in your tableview delegate. I made a PR on your github project.

Comment: @alexkent Thank you very much! With your help, I can switch to diffable data source with Combine!

Comment: @wildcat Glad it helped. Although… your example project does make me wonder if the code in my answer above is at all necessary. Everything appears to work fine with an empty implementation of `tableView(moveRowAt:to:)`.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to do that by subclassing the `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` class like this:

```swift
class MyDataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Int> {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        // your code to update source of truth
        // make a new snapshot from your source of truth
        // apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}
```

And then you can `override` any data source methods that you need for your implementation.